# How to group on column and sum up multiple individual value of column?

Tags: mongodb, nosql, metabase

So below is MongoDB collection/table structure:

id - unique id
stage - {id:unique id,name:TRIGGER OTP}
customer - customer_mobile_no
date - date

stage column also contains below entries

```
{"id":"abc","name":"CREATE REPAYMENT LINK"}
{"id":"abl","stage.name":"OTP FORM"}
{"id":"atc","stage.name":"TRIGGER OTP"},
{"id":"akc","stage.name":"VERIFY | RESEND"}
{"id":"agc","stage.name":"VERIFY OTP"},
{"id":"afc","stage.name":"LOAN DETAILS"},
{"id":"aac","stage.name":"PAYMENT SCREEN"}
```

if i run below query:

```
[
    {"$match":
            {"$and":[
                {"stage.name":"CREATE REPAYMENT LINK"}]
            }
    },
    {"$group":{_id:"$customer",count:{$sum:1}}},
    {"$project":{id:0,Customer:"$_id","CREATE REPAYMENT LINK":"$count"}}
]
```

i will get output like:

```
Customer    CREATE REPAYMENT LINK
1122334455      2
1123334455      1
1124334455      1
1125334455      3
```

now is there any way to count multiple values or achieve the below output:

```
Customer    CREATE REPAYMENT LINK    TRIGGER OTP    OTP FORM
1122334455      2                       3              2
1123334455      1                       4              1
1124334455      1                       1              3
1125334455      3                       0              1
```

Comment: You will find some similar posts if you search for _"mongodb group sum condition"_.

Comment: @prasad_ I didn't find any since days, That's why I asked. I want to get count for every customer that how many times this unique customer have triggere OTP, created payment link, submit OTP form. By group them with customer mobile number and apply condition I am able to get only one column count. I want to count every event for unique customer. If you can help in that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, I'm able to get to answer but not for all customers. only one, by below query:

```
[
    {"$match":
        {"$and":[
            {"$or":[
                {"stage.name":"CREATE REPAYMENT LINK"},
                {"stage.name":"OTP FORM"},
                {"stage.name":"TRIGGER OTP"},
                {"stage.name":"VERIFY | RESEND"}
                {"stage.name":"VERIFY OTP"},
                {"stage.name":"LOAN DETAILS"},
                {"stage.name":"PAYMENT SCREEN"},
                {"stage.name":"FINAL SCREEN"},
                {"stage.name":"process timeout"}]
            },{"$and":[
                {"customer":{"$eq":{{mobile_no}}}}]
            }]
        }    
    },
    {"$facet":{
        "CREATE_REPAYMENT_LINK": [
            {"$match":{"$and":[{"stage.name":"CREATE REPAYMENT LINK"}]}},
            {"$group": {_id: "$customer",count:{$sum:1}}}],
        
        "OTP_FORM": [
            {"$match":{"$and":[{"stage.name":"OTP FORM"}]}},
            {"$group": {_id: "$customer",count:{$sum:1}}}],
        
        "TRIGGER_OTP": [
            {"$match":{"$and":[{"stage.name":"TRIGGER OTP"}]}},
            {"$group": {_id: "$customer",count:{$sum:1}}}],
            
        "VERIFY_RESEND": [
            {"$match":{"$and":[{"stage.name":"VERIFY | RESEND"}]}},
            {"$group": {_id: "$customer",count:{$sum:1}}}],    
            
        "VERIFY_OTP": [
            {"$match":{"$and":[{"stage.name":"VERIFY OTP"}]}},
            {"$group": {_id: "$customer",count:{$sum:1}}}],
            
        "LOAN_DETAILS": [
            {"$match":{"$and":[{"stage.name":"LOAN DETAILS"}]}},
            {"$group": {_id: "$customer",count:{$sum:1}}}],
            
        "PAYMENT_SCREEN": [
            {"$match":{"$and":[{"stage.name":"PAYMENT SCREEN"}]}},
            {"$group": {_id: "$customer",count:{$sum:1}}}],
            
        "FINAL_SCREEN": [
            {"$match":{"$and":[{"stage.name":"FINAL SCREEN"}]}},
            {"$group": {_id: "$customer",count:{$sum:1}}}]
        
        }
    },
    {"$project":{_id:0,"Customer":{{mobile_no}},
                "CREATE REPAYMENT LINK":{$arrayElemAt: [ "$CREATE_REPAYMENT_LINK.count", 0 ]},
                "OTP FORM":{$arrayElemAt: [ "$OTP_FORM.count", 0 ]},
                "TRIGGER OTP":{$arrayElemAt: [ "$TRIGGER_OTP.count", 0 ]},
                "VERIFY | RESEND":{$arrayElemAt: [ "$VERIFY_RESEND.count", 0 ]},
                "VERIFY OTP":{$arrayElemAt: [ "$VERIFY_OTP.count", 0 ]},
                "LOAN DETAILS":{$arrayElemAt: [ "$LOAN_DETAILS.count", 0 ]},
                "PAYMENT SCREEN":{$arrayElemAt: [ "$PAYMENT_SCREEN.count", 0 ]},
                "FINAL SCREEN":{$arrayElemAt: [ "$FINAL_SCREEN.count", 0 ]}
    }}
]
```

Output as i expected:

```
Customer    OTP FORM    TRIGGER OTP VERIFY | RESEND     VERIFY OTP  LOAN DETAILS
1122334455     12           12          9               4            4
```